# Why scrollIntoView() only works with view reference?

Tags: angular, getelementbyid, viewchild, js-scrollintoview, queryselector

I'm trying to use scrollIntoView() for my Angular 2 project. I have a container div with overflow that grow when data arrives to the component and I need to scroll to the bottom of the div as data arrives.
If I use a button and pass the reference through it, this work fine.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
<button (click)="scrollTo(target)"></button>
-----
-----
<!-- Dynamic content here -->
-----
-----
<div #target class="target" id="target"></div>
```

And in the component:

```
public scrollTo(el: HTMLElement) {
    el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to use a button, I need to call the scrollTo function within the component. 
I have tried to use to use @ViewChildren, document.querySelector and document.getElementById but nothing works.

Example:

1)

```
@ViewChildren('target') target: ElementRef;
```

And in the function:

```
public scrollTo() {
    this.target.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

2)

```
public scrollTo() {
    let element = document.getElementById('target');
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

3)

```
public scrollTo() {
    let element = document.querySelector('.target');
    element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

En all cases if I print the element by console, the result is the same:

```
<div class="target" id="target" _ngcontent-ema-86=""></div>
```

But the scroll goes to the bottom of the container div only with the button.

Additional data: The project is a VSTO add-in for PowerPoint and it should run on IE11.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem due to smooth behavior support in IE11. Have you tried without it?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've tried with Chrome too and the result is the same.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `ViewChild` not `ViewChildren`. `ViewChild` is used when you want to access a single element from the template. `ViewChildren` is used when you have multiple elements in the template with the same id (`#target`). The latter will give you an array.

Try this instead.

```js
@ViewChild('target', { static: true }) target: ElementRef;

public scrollTo() {
    this.target.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
}
```

Check out the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for more details on `ViewChild`.

Comment: But he also tries with querySelector, so I think the problem in another place. But you absolutely right, `ViewChild` should be used in this case.

Comment: My mistake, effectively I am using @ViewChild but Angular 2 don't support { static: true }

Comment: @CesarHerrera In Angular 2, simply use `@ViewChild('target') target: ElementRef;`